# How to Get Formatted Date String In React Native

Tags: javascript

In many apps we can see the date formatting like this.

```
If it's today, then print hh:mm,
If it's yesterday, then print yesterday,
If it's in this week, then print day of week, (ex, Wednesday)
If it's in this year, then print MM/dd
else print YY/MM/dd
```

Something like this.
How can I implement in React Native or javascript?
Is there library for this?

Comment: Did you check https://momentjs.com/? It's kind of a good starting point as it does a lot of thing with time in JS.

Comment: Some what similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097216/momentjs-get-if-date-is-this-week-this-month-or-this-year

Answer (score 0):

Use library [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/). There is function `isSame` which compare given date with year,month or day. Like

```
moment().isSame('2010-01-01', 'year');  // true
moment().isSame('2011-01-01', 'month'); // false, different year
moment().isSame('2010-02-01', 'day'); //
moment().isSame('2010-02-01', 'week'); //
```

In your case, 1st on

```
const dateString = moment().isSame('2018-01-01', 'day') ? moment('2018-01-01 5:55').format('hh:mm') : else check for other condition
```

Better go from year to month to week and week to day.