# Vue - How to search filter specific part in data?

Tags: vue.js, filter

I'm making a little Vue app with firestore.

I select the data from date time picker and send the data in this format to db.

**{{date}} : 2018-09-15T00:00:00.000Z**

Here is 09 showing month.

I have a v-for loop like this:

```
<tbody v-for="item in filteredList">
    <tr>
    <td>{{item.date.slice(0,10)}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have this filter in the Computed property:

```
computed: {
    filteredList() {
        return this.items.filter(item => { return item.date.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) })
   }
}
```

So i want to search with input or selecting dropdown which will filter the items based on the month:

2018-09-15T00:00:00.000Z . from the 09 in this case

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a filter (text, dropdown, etc) that is

1. bound to the data member `filterText`.
2. Has a 2 digit string value to represent month.
3. Uses empty string to mean 'no filter'.

You would do this:

```
computed: {
  filteredList() {
    return this.items.filter(item => {
      const field = parseInt(item.date.substring(5, 7)) // the month part of the date

      if (this.filterText === '') return true
      else return field === this.filterText
    })
  }
}
```

Here is a sample filter element, binding to `filterText`

```
<select v-model='filterText'>
    <option v-for='n in 12' :value='pad2(n)'>{{n}}</option>
</select>
```

Bound to data

```
  data: {
    filterText:'03'
  },
```

And a padding method

```
methods: {
     pad2(number) {
  if (number<=99) { number = ("0"+number).slice(-2); }
  return number;
}
```

Comment: if i will search with input my v-model on input for search will be filterText ?

Comment: For example, filterText will be bound to the value of your select box. ('01', '02', '03', etc)

Comment: @CihanZengin I added some more ideas to the answer.

Comment: not worked :( giving white screen not showing data from v-for loop and not showing any error :/

Comment: @CihanZengin I had index wrong.  Check out codepen too, https://codepen.io/Flamenco/pen/OowNoK.  I was using (5,2) instead of (5,7).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) if you work a lot with times since it supports tons of operations.

[Here some more Docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) and [a related SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097216/momentjs-get-if-date-is-this-week-this-month-or-this-year)

Comment: `date-fns` is the better momentjs, as its modular structure allows importing only the needed functions.

Comment: @BennettDams thanks for that interesting comment, i readed a bit more about it and you are right, still learning every day ^^ thanks again and here are article recommendation https://raygun.com/blog/moment-js-vs-date-fns/

Comment: may you understand me not correctly, my problem is not formatting time data, my problem is accessing the first and second character of data with filtering